# Interpreting Predictions from the Log-Linear Model (or Log-Log Model...)

Tags: regression, back-transformation

I understand that when we fit an OLS regression to the log(y) (as either a log-linear or log-log model), the predicted value from that model [log(y).hat] cannot be simply exponentiated to solve for y.hat. I have read several authors of econometrics books that suggest just reporting the prediction as log(y).hat (i.e., NOT back transforming it from the natural log space to the original units of y) for this reason. My question is: Is there than any meaningful interpretation of log(y).hat?

For example, in the OLS Linear-Linear model:

y.hat = the average value of the response variable when X = x

Is there a meaningful interpretation to log(y).hat?

In economics, the slope of the Log-Linear model is understood as a semi-elasticity:

beta1 = A 1-unit increase in x is associated with a change of 100(beta1)% in y.

Furthermore, the slope of the Log-Log model is understood as an elasticity:

beta1 = A 1% increase in x is associated with a change of beta1% in y.

====

Does the prediction [log(y).hat] have some kind of semi-elasticity meaning for the Log-Linear model (or elasticity meaning for the Log-Log model)?